# RestSharp ParameterType.RequestBody to Refit

Tags: c#, request, restsharp, refit

Is there a way to convert a RestSharp implementation that includes something like this:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

to a Refit implementation?

I have no solutions atm.